# Plotting $y^2(a+x)=x^2(a-x)$ where $a\gt 0$ using $x=a\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, plane-curves, parametrization

I am trying to plot the curve described by the equality $y^2(a+x)=x^2(a-x)$. It is clear that the domain of the expression is $x\in (-a,a]$. This requires a simple application of the general methods of curve tracing for the graph of $y\sqrt{a+x}=x\sqrt{a-x}$. And then the obtained graph can be mirrored in the $x$-axis due to symmetry.

I am trying to do this using a different method, that I suppose is called polar curve tracing. Substituting $x=a\cos(2\theta)$ seems favorable due to two reasons, one, the domain of the function is satisfied by $x=a\cos(2\theta)\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}-\{\theta:\cos(2\theta)+1=0\}$ and, two, the rational expression $\frac{a-x}{a+x}$ simplifies to $\tan^2(\theta)$. And so the curve becomes $y^2=a^2\cos^{2}(2\theta)\tan^2\theta$. Or for what it's worth $y=\pm a\cos(2\theta)\tan(\theta)$.

But I don't see how to map the curve from the $\theta y$ plane to the $xy$ plane. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the curve is actually defined by $x=a\cos(2\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle of the point (i.e. not your $\theta$). Though I haven't made a proof.

Comment: @Milten I can easily construct  $y=\pm a\cos(2\theta)\tan(\theta)$, how to map it from the $\theta y$ plane to $xy$ plane. In that sense, the question is not entirely about using polar curve tracing methods. But another method is also welcome.

Comment: I would rewrite it to $r=a(2\cos\theta + \frac{1}{\cos\theta})$ probably.

Comment: @Milten It should probably be $r=a(2\cos(\theta) -\sec(\theta))$.